# Is the OLS estimator ${w} = ({X}^T{X})^{-1}{X}^T{y}$ or ${w} = ({X}{X}^T)^{-1}{X}{y}^T$?

Tags: regression, matrix

the closed form solution of the weights for the ordinary least squares problem is given by $\mathbf{w} = (\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{y}$. This is the almost 'universal' form that I have found in all derivatives and textbooks, except for one source.

In this source:
https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4780/2018fa/lectures/lecturenote08.html, however, the least squares solution is given by $\mathbf{w} = (\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^T)^{-1}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{y}^T$.

I am trying to show these two are equivalent, but not successful.

I took the transpose of the first form, but I only have: $\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^T)^{-1}$. Is there any additional assumption here?

Comment: In the source you quote the model is *explicitly* written in terms of $w^\prime$ rather than $w.$  Thus, you need to transpose everything when relating it to models written in terms of $w.$  It's important to read the details!  That source, btw, is (grievously) remiss in not distinguishing the parameter vector $w$ from its estimate.  Therein lies the source of many misconceptions about regression and statistical procedures generally.

Answer (score 4):

In the second form, the authors transposed $X$ compared to the first form. In other words:

- in the first form, the rows are observations and the columns are features;
- in the second form, the rows are features and the columns are observations.